# CodeIgniter just show one result from my table

Tags: codeigniter

```
SELECT * FROM image;
```

I am using that query to get data from image table, when i checked it using this query directly into mysql commandline it showed 3 result like this

```
3 rows in set (0.00 sec);
```

but, when i try to fetch it from codeigniter using query or active_record, it just show me 1 result. This is my code

```
class Produk_model extends CI_Model{
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function get_phome(){
        $this->db->select('nama_produk, nama_seo, nama_kategori, seo_kategori, nominal_harga');
        $this->db->join('kategori','kategori.id_kategori=produk.id_kategori');
        $this->db->join('harga','harga.id_produk=produk.id_produk');
        $q=$this->db->get('produk');
        if($q->num_rows()){
            return $q;
        }
    }

    function get_all_pimage(){
        $q=$this->db->get('image');
        if($q->num_rows()>0){
            return $q;
        }
    }

    function get_by_kategori($kategori_name=''){
        $this->db->select('nama_kategori, seo_kategori, nama_produk, nama_seo, nominal_harga, url_img');
        $this->db->join('kategori', 'kategori.id_kategori=produk.id_kategori');
        $this->db->join('harga','harga.id_produk=produk.id_produk');
        $this->db->join('image','image.id_produk=produk.id_produk');
        $this->db->where('seo_kategori',$kategori_name);
        $q=$this->db->get('produk');
        if($q->num_rows()){
            return $q;
        }
    }

    function get_by_produk($produk_name=''){
        $this->db->select('produk.id_produk, nama_produk, nama_seo, short_desc, min_beli, nominal_harga');
        $this->db->join('produk_detil','produk_detil.id_produk=produk.id_produk');
        $this->db->join('harga','harga.id_produk=produk.id_produk');
        $this->db->where('nama_seo', $produk_name);
        $q=$this->db->get('produk');
        if($q->num_rows()){
            return $q;
        }
    }

    function get_img_by_produk($produk_id=''){
        $this->db->select('url_img');
        $this->db->where('id_produk', $produk_id);
        $q=$this->db->get('image');
        if($q->num_rows()){
            return $q;
        }
    }
}
```

i am trying to use get_all_pimage() with the function below from my controller

```
function home(){
            $this->load->model('produk_model');
            $data['konten']=$this->produk_model->get_phome()->result();
            $data['img']=$this->produk_model->get_all_pimage()->row_array();
            $this->load->view('frontend/home', $data);
        }
```

but it just showed me 1 result, like this :

```
Array
(
 [id_image] => 2
 [id_produk] => PRD002
 [seo_image] => pastel-1
 [url_img] => pastel-1.jpg
)
```

i am confused, why it can be happened. because i don't know where is the mistake . Thank for your helping

Comment: Which one of these class functions are you trying to run? Can you provide an example of how you're calling the function?

Comment: sorry, i am trying to run it with this function $data['img']=$this->produk_model->get_all_pimage()->row_array();

Comment: Theres your problem   ->row_array()  gets only a single row

Comment: just leave that off...you're already returning the whole array in the function

Comment: [SOLVED] Oops, thank you very much, KyleK. are have an alternative way to gets a multiple row with array ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change function to..

```
function get_all_pimage(){
$q=$this->db->get('image');
if($q->num_rows()>0){
    return $q->result_array();
 }
 }
```

Take row->Array() off your call...like so..

```
 $data['img']=$this->produk_model->get_all_pimage();
```

Then foreach...

```
foreach($data['img'] as $val){
  //display you data
}
```